# Changing background-color of bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I'm trying to change this white color.

Code:

```
            <div id="accordion" class="panel-group" >
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h2 class="panel-title">
                            <a href="#one" class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" >O que é</a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="one" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>
                                É um evento que visita vários bares e baladas em uma mesma noite. Organizado por quem conhece a cidade, é uma ótima oportunidade de curtir a noite na companhia de pessoas interessantes por um preço acessível. Por isso, além do próprio público local, o produto é bem recomendado para turistas.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

is very difficult override bootstrap css, i'm stock in this for 2 hours, any help is very welcome.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/celicoo/wjmjy1fy/ @GSaunders

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.panel-body {background-color:black;}
```

if it doesn't work then:

```
.panel-body {background-color:black !important;}
```

Comment: lol.. so easy, did you search in google or something like that?

Comment: No x,D 
i know stuff... mopra.dk

Comment: What you should know though.. is that !important is not a traditional solution, i will always try to avoid using such overwrite commands because it will just create useless code for the browser to render. And it can become a problem for some browsers (pff IE).

But yea, if you use a bootstrap i see no other solutions :D 
- you could edit the source code in the bootstrap but i guess u would need more knowlegde.

Answer (score 1):

On bootstrap 4+ use bg-dark as collapse is indeed a card. Follow the card example:

```
<div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="max-width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-header">Header</div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Dark card title</h5>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```