# Bootstrap Accordion Change Default Colors

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to change the default colors for an Accordion in Bootstrap. I have managed to change nearly everything (header, body, etc) satisfactorily but I am still stuck with what seems like a border (but I am unsure) between the header and body. I've tried the following solutions:

1. [Stack... Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985812/override-bootstrap-accordion-colors-in-bootstrap-for-angularjs)
2. [Stack.. Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764680/changing-background-color-of-bootstrap-accordion)
3. [SitePoint 1](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/bootstrap-3-accordian-onclick-accordion-background-should-be-change/98839)

(and they have helped immensely in getting to where I am now, thanks!) but I have not managed to drill down quite enough.

My HTML is as follows;

```
<div class="container content" id="faq">
    <h2>FAQ</h2>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
                        ...
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
                        ...
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    ... 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">
                        ...
                    </a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                   ...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div><!--end #accordion -->
</div><!--end .container #faq-->
```

and I've tried the following CSS;

```
.container >.panel-group >.panel-default {
border: 0; !important;}

.container >.panel-group >.panel-default >.panel-heading {
background-color: #27ae60; !important;
border: 0; !important;}

.panel {
background-color: #2ecc71;
border: 5px solid #27ae60;}
```

I'm unsure what I am missing, any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The `.panel-body` has a border. Try this `.panel-group .panel-heading+.panel-collapse>.panel-body {border-top:0;}`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, much appreciated :)